# CloudFront - Serve static website from S3, route API requests to EC2 on custom port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a similar setup as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360255/how-to-serve-static-media-contents-only-from-s3-and-others-from-ec2?rq=1).

I have set up CloudFront as a CDN. In CloudFront I created two origins:

- The S3 Bucket serving static contents (works fine)
- The EC2 machine with some API server running on port 8888

Now in CloudFront I have added one behavior (`precedence 0`) that all requests to "`/api/*`" are forwarded to the EC2 instance, including all header and whatsoever. The whole thing should be serving via HTTPS (S3 and EC2).

The problem is that requests to /api seem to time-out. I'm not sure where the problem is. Maybe it is related to:

- The port - where can/should I reflect that the port number is `8888`? I have also tried to define the HTTPS port in the origin settings as "`8888`" instead of "`443`"
- Some other security or mapping settings?

**Note**: I have not yet updated the DNS settings, that CloudFront points to the real domain. Currently using the domain generated by CloudFront only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the port is the issue. I'm not aware of a way to forward some requests to a different origin server port via CloudFront. Why not put an Application Load Balancer in front of the EC2 instance, listening on the standard port 443 and forwarding to port 8888 on the server? That would also enable you to scale up your API server pool in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this next week, and will reply then.

Comment: That was the most flexible solution, as the Load Balancer allows many routing options based on rules.

Answer (score 0):

I would try installing Nginx on the EC2 server to accept the requests (80/443) and proxy them to port 8888. Seems a simpler alternative than running ALB.